# How to surface content from tvos app in the TV app

Tags: swift, tvos

Since version 10, Apple's tvOS features the "TV" App (U.S. only), which aggregates content from Apple and other video providers/apps.

Is there an API to allow content from my own tvOS app to be indexed so that it appears in the "TV" app search?

Comment: No public API. Invite only.